# cassification of sequence data with tflearn

Tags: tensorflow, tflearn

I would like to train a model using `tflearn` for sequence classification.

E.g if I had a sequence of 16000 points which through convolution were reduced to 4000, and each point could be classed as one of 64 categories, the model would then look something like this:

```
network = input_data(shape=[None, 1600, 1], name='input')
network = conv_1d(network, 32, 11, activation='relu', padding="same")
network = max_pool_1d(network, 4, strides=4)
network = fully_connected(network, 64, activation='softmax')
network = regression(network, 
                     optimizer='adam', 
                     learning_rate=0.01,
                     loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
                     name='target',
                     to_one_hot=True,
                     n_classes=(4000, 64),
                     batch_size=1)
```

This is relatively straightfowrard to do in keras but I am finding it hard to express in tflearn.

Comment: What is the exact question you have?

Comment: @iga I am asking how I train a model where the output is one-hot encoded but 2D